# Sitecore 10.3 xp1 LTS2019 Experience editor not working

Tags: sitecore, next.js13

I have NextJS application built with Sitecore and we are unable to open the Experience Editor.

We are getting the following error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.]
>
> [ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'Home'.
> The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Home'.
> The current route url is: '{controller}/{action}'.]
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +171
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +261
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +77
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1128
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134

What can be causing the problem?